# Azure push notification on iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, azure

i want to add Azure framework on iOS swift app for push notification , but i can't find a swift guide . Can anyone Help me to set up thanks

Comment: For push notification from notification hub. You can simply follow learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/notification-hubs/… For using it in Swift Project Make sure you add bridging header in your project and import correct file name #import "WindowsAzureMessaging/WindowsAzureMessaging.h"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following URL:
 - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-how-to-use-client-library/

There's a section titled "How to: Register push templates to send cross-platform notifications" that includes code for both Objective-C and Swift.

Here is a screenshot:
[image: iOS Push Notifications]